# xcodebuild command fails in Gitlab Runner

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, xcodebuild

I am setting up Gitlab CI in my project, ***xcodebuild*** command fails in gitlab-runner. However, the following command to clean Xcode Project works perfectly in terminal

```
 xcodebuild clean -workspace ~/Documents/iOS\ Projects/{ProjectName}.xcworkspace -scheme {ProjectScheme}
```

When I added this script to 'yml' file and pushed it to repo, gitlab job says, *xcodebuild: command not found*

[image: screenshot1]

Steps taken to solve this issue, but still not resolved:

1. Provided path to same script using /usr/bin/xcodebuild,
   says "No such file or directory"
   [image: screenshot2]
2. Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools set to Xcode 13.0
3. Run `xcode-select -print-path` and it shows `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, which seems to be correct, but gitlab-runner is somehow unable to find the *xcodebuild*. It seems gitlab-runner is confused with directory.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when using `fastlane`. If you installed the runner on macOs using the official guide, try to print out the $PATH variable and check its contents. In my case it was missing a few paths which I added in a `before_script` block, i.e.:

```yaml
before_script:
  - export PATH="/Users/MyUser/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

Be sure to use the shell executor and the direct macOs installation, otherwise the runner won't work